# Containers for sandboxing

Tags: linux, virtualization, container

I'm trying to find a container stack for sandboxing and and would like to know which stacks do that particular job well. By sandboxing I mean running applications so that security flaws are confined to the application.

I want such applications to be able to be run as cron jobs. I also want almost absolute control over where various files are stored and especially by default.

Minor rant. I remember how upset I was when I discovered that VBox was dumping image diffs in my very small home folder, when I set aside a rather large amount of disc base for things VM related!

PS: I don't know if it somehow got editted out, or if I simply forgot, but whatever scheme should be automatic. I want cron jobs to be able to start and stop containers.

Comment: The tag name was somewhat confusing, `lxc` is short for Linux Containers. I edited that. `lxc` is probably exactly what you want. The only major decisions then will be whether [tag:userns] is involved or whether the container runs privileged and what the backing storage shall be: directory, LVM or any of the other options.

Comment: have you looked into docker?

Comment: @0xC0000022L lxc is dumb. it presupposes that LXC will be the answer.

Comment: 0xC0000022L, AFAIU lxc stores the image in /var/. That is a far cry from "absolute control over where various files are stored".

Comment: @edvinas.me, I know very little of docker. I saw several talks. The commercial part of the talk sounds great, but when I get to the sctual demo, I cannot make out what is on the screen.  The one thing that does seem clear to me is that everything goes through a docker command. It seems to me that would prevent control of where everything is.

Comment: @Mouse.The.Lucky.Dog: Then don't call it "Linux Containers", call it just `container` or `containers` and put a `linux` tag with it, because the term "Linux Containers" is already tied to `lxc` whether you like it or not and equally ... Besides, you apparently haven't read my comment either, because [tag:userns] requires no such thing as storing it in `/var`, not does `lxc` *force* you to use that path in any way. It's merely the **default**.

Answer (score 0):

My impression is that Docker is currently the de facto standard for containers.  Very interested to hear if other people think that Google's container system or bare lxc is better, and why.  Or if there is another option.

Comment: Docker is merely a very convenient wrapper around LXC, nothing more, nothing less. And since Docker has no support for [tag:userns] containers, I'd not consider it a "standard" at all. Saying Docker is the standard for containers is like saying Node.js is the standard for scripts in websites. It disregards/ignores the *underlying* technology.

Comment: The talk I've seen suggests that Google's containers don't use namespaces at all.

Comment: @Mouse.The.Lucky.Dog: it appears to make use of namespaces from looking at the source and [the docs](https://github.com/google/lmctfy/blob/master/PRIMER.md), definitely of cgroups, though. See [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/lmctfy/e6oGQELK2oA) for a comparison.

Comment: @0xC0000022L Docker doesn't use LXC by default anymore it uses its own library called libcontainer.  http://www.infoq.com/news/2014/03/docker_0_9 Also Node.js runs applications on the server, which is what I think you meant but you accidentally typed "in websites".  How important is userns? Docker has a lot of other features see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17989306/what-does-docker-add-to-just-plain-lxc I am (obviously) on the Docker bandwagon at this point but if that is actually a bad idea I need to adjust..

Comment: @JasonLivesay: wow, everyday you learn something is a good day. Thanks for taking the time to respond, much appreciated!

Comment: The very first thing in the talk "Let Me  Contain That For You!" is that Google has not yet incorporated namespaces, and that that will take a lot of effort,  and Google does not need it. That was October 2013.